# Appraise the statement: “For the model  = 0 + 1 + , 1 reflects the causal effect of  on .” Ask

Tags: linear-regression, self-study

not sure if this was the right place to ask my question, but I saw some questions regarding linear regression so I'd thought I would try to get some answers here. I just started learning about linear regression so this is the homework posed to me.

I assume that the statement is true since 1 is the coefficient for . And its the coefficient that would determine if the slope (i.e. the relationship) is positive or negative.

Am I missing out anything or what should I expound on?

Thanks for reading and for the guides and opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the forum. Homework is not so well received here in the forum. But still a fair question in my view.

You have two aspects here. In principle you are right that $\beta_1$ is the slope of $x_1$ (you can say the marginal effect of $x_1$ on $y$) and $\beta_0$ is the intercept. This is simply a linear function of form $f(x)=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x$.

However, to claim "causality", a few more things are required. First, you need to make the assumption that there is a causal relation between $x$ and $y$ and $x$ must be *exogenous*.

Another important aspect is, that if there are additional variables with a causal influence on $y$, say $x_2$, you cannot really claim that $\beta_1$ is the causal effect on $...$, because you omitted $x_2$, so that your model suffers from the *omitted variable bias*. To claim for causality you need to make sure that your model reflects the data generating process in a proper way.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. When you say x must be exogenous, do you mean that x must be an independent variable?

Comment: This means that x determines y, but y does not determine x, so the „direction“ of causality. If you think about the number of police officers (x) and crime (y) you could not claim that x is exogenous, because cities with higher crime rates might hire more police officers, so in this case there is a „more complex“ interaction between x and y.